# Git push outside of main directory

Tags: git, github

I am starting using git and wanted to add my test-repo on github, but I'm doing something wrong and it doesn't work as I want to.

I have following structure:

```
my_project
    - .git  (git root directory)
    - autoload
    - modules
        - test_module
            - test
                file_1.txt
            - test 2
                file_2.txt
    - public
```

After push I want to have 2 directories on github:

```
    - test
        file_1.txt
    - test 2
        file_2.txt
```

But I get:

```
    - modules
        - test_module
            - test
                file_1.txt
            - test 2
                file_2.txt
```

This is what I have try

```
cd modules/test_module
git add --all
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin remote_repository_URL
git push origin master
```

What am I doing wrong?
Should I init git repository under test_module? But what If I have severals modules? I'll need to init repositories under all of them?

Comment: The tree structure of the repo hosted on GitHub will be the same as that of your local repo. No way around that.

Comment: So you mean I have to create repoositories for all modules under their name to get folder structure I wrote above?

Comment: Yes, that is how Git works.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I init git repository under test_module?

Yes, and add a remote referencing your GitHub repo (which is the one where you want to see the expected folder structure)

```
cd module
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://<username>@github.com/<username>/test-repo
git push -u origin master
```

> But what If I have severals modules? I'll need to init repositories under all of them?

Yes, if you want each of them to have their own separate history.
In that case, you could consider referencing them in the main parent repo as **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.